# Hybris Admin - "Localize Types" fails with a NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, sap-commerce-cloud

From my Hybris Admin tool (http://localhost:9001/admin), when I run the command "Update running hybris Multichannel Suite" with only the option "Localize types" selected, I get the following error:

```
11:19:31,146 [hybrisHTTP5] INFO  [Initialization] Localizing types ...
11:19:32,481 [hybrisHTTP5] INFO  [EJBTools] pk 8796118941778 does no longer exist.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.CollectionType.isAssignableFrom(CollectionType.java:545)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.localization.TypeLocalization.resortTypes(TypeLocalization.java:520)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.localization.TypeLocalization.localizeTypes(TypeLocalization.java:177)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.localization.TypeLocalization.localizeTypes(TypeLocalization.java:143)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.doInitialize(Initialization.java:374)
        at org.apache.jsp.init_005finitialize_jsp._jspService(init_005finitialize_jsp.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:366)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:11
9)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens due to what is previously logged as "INFO":

```
INFO  [EJBTools] pk 8796118941778 does no longer exist.
```

To solve this:
1. Run the following query against the hybris database.

```
SELECT *
  FROM collectiontypes
  WHERE elementtypepk NOT IN (SELECT pk FROM composedtypes
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT pk FROM ATOMICTYPES);
```

1. The returned rows reference types that no longer exist and is somehow an artifact of previous upgrades.
2. Deleting those rows should resolve the issue.
3. Update Hybris.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an "ant all" when you create an Item type then restart the server and update the system ticking the localize item types. Before all this did you use Hmc to localise the type you created? you need to export the type, copy paste the content over in *locales-en.properties.